# Client webmail for GMail in AS3: best approach

Tags: php, actionscript-3, webmail

I was reading questions and answers about building a webmail to access gmail by imap. It seams not easy task, however, there is a lot of ready stuff. I was wondering about do it in flash, as3 ( no sure what google will think about ).

My idea is start with a good and ready webmail client that has the code easy to transform into a server-side communication php software. So I only make the interface and structures to make request and receive answers, and the server-side php talks with gmail. In this case, can't be some php coding with interface and functions together, but some php5 with modular architecture, I guess.

Edited: Will be Flash in a browser. The server side will be an Apache and php5.

Any ideas?

Comment: What platform will this be running on?  If in a browser, don't use flash.

Comment: I'd write above about platform. I'm not trying to discuss the code itself here, just ideas of using ready php code as server-side part. Why not flash?

Comment: Because flash player is slowly vanishing.  The platform is very healthy for native applications, but the vast majority of tablet computers and phones do not have the ability to use the flash player browser plugin.

Comment: I know, it's for a specific case, will be very simple. And we need it to run in every browse, it's not happening for Ajax apps. I was using homebanking and runs only in FireFox. Than's no good for us. Flash is vanishing again? I heard this since Macromedia days...

Comment: Mobile browsers are on the verge of surpassing desktop browsers, flash (as a browser plugin) is no longer a viable solution for web developers unless creating for a specific browser/client (or if you do HTML fallbacks).   Flash is still great as a native application though on mobile and desktop alike and isn't going away anytime soon there.     If you need every browser, then you'll have use native web technology.

Comment: Yes, Flash on the browser is being killed by HTML5. As a developer I love Flash, but I think this is quite deserved. It seems the only advantage these days is for video players.

Comment: Is there some useful information to share, or you'll just keep with spam?

Answer (score 2):

So far, the best approach to the task I've found is trough this:

[PyAMF](http://www.pyamf.org/index.html)

This is a solution to webmail in Python that talks with Flash. As the GMail API got updated Python libraries in Google Developers, I think we already start working with a great email with half the way ready. I asked a friend about this (I think he works with Python) and will see about the possibilities.

If you have some opinion, please share, but pleas don't come with that Ajax+jQuery+HTML5+something solution because the purpose of this is to explore the alternative.